# Select single column from array returned by GetQuote extension

Tags: formula, libreoffice-calc

Ted Schlossmacher's free [GetQuote extension for OpenOffice.org Calc](http://getquote-tedsoft.blogspot.com/) allows users to access quotes for several types of symbols tracked by Yahoo! Finance. Specifically, the `GETHISTORY()` function returns a range of past and present quotes.

After installing the extension, try highlighting a 5-column range and then typing `=GETHISTORY("PETR4.SA",1,TODAY()-1)` (you might need to use semicolons instead of commas) and then pressing `Ctrl+Shift+Return`. That should provide you with date, open, high, low and close quotes for PETR4, the preferred stock of Brazilian oil giant Petrobras S.A.

My question is: how can I, in one cell, insert a formula that would return me the value of the 5th column of the above array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with the `INDEX` function. You don't need to use ctrl+shift+enter for it to work as it does't return an array.

```
=INDEX(GETHISTORY("PETR4.SA",1,TODAY()-1),1,5)
```

The 2 end parameters are `row`,`column`, and are a 1-based index into the array.

More information about `INDEX` can be found on any Excel website, or in the LibreOffice Calc help at https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#INDEX

Comment: Very elegant and effective solution. Thanks, Mike!

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday's closing price can be retrieved using a second argument, for example:
=GETQUOTE("TD.TO",21)

From the manual:
GETQUOTE can fetch 31 types of quotes. The types are numbered from 0 to 30. The function accepts these numbers as the second argument.

```
 0 = Last traded price 
 1 = Change in price for the day 
 2 = Opening price of the day
 3 = High price of the day 
 4 = Low price of the day 
 5 = Volume 
 6 = Average Daily Volume 
 7 = Ask Price 
 8 = Bid Price 
 9 = Book Value 
10 = Dividend/Share 
11 = Earnings/Share 
12 = Earnings/Share Estimate Current Year 
13 = Earnings/Share Estimate Next Year 
14 = Earnings/Share Estimate Next Quarter 
15 = 52-week low
16 = Change from 52-week low
17 = 52-week high
18 = Change from 52-week high
19 = 50-day Moving Average
20 = 200-day Moving Average
21 = Previous Close
22 = Price/Earning Ratio
23 = Dividend Yield
24 = Price/Sales
25 = Price/Book
26 = PEG Ratio
27 = Price/EPS Estimate Current Year
28 = Price/EPS Estimate Next Year
29 = Short Ratio
30 = 1-year Target Price
```

Comment: That's very useful, thanks! Too bad it doesn't seem to work with currency exchange rates (`GETQUOTE("usdeur=x",21)`, for example, yields an error).

Comment: Retrying my comment - yes it doesn't seem to accept a second argument. That may be the way yahoo finance manages currencies but I do not know since I don't trade them. However, I see that yesterday's closing price is shown at [link](http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=usdeur=X), so it's unclear why one couldn't retrieve it.

Comment: Hah - discovered a way to make it work! Call it this way: =getquote("usdeur=x,21")  ie. with everything inside the double quotes, Must be a yahoo quirk, possibly in the way they interpret the equals sign.

Comment: `getquote("usdeur=x,21")` seems to give the current value, i.e., the same as `getquote("usdeur=x")`, doesn't it?

Comment: Not in my testing - of course you'd have to check when the markets are open. This morning (I  am GMT -400) I get different values for the two which supports that getquote("usdeur=x,21") does in fact produce yesterday's closing price.

Comment: Hmm - upon further testing, I am getting inconsistent results, enough that I wouldn't trust them for any currency trading decisions. If I can obtain accurate results, I will return here and post what I've found.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only the latest price (which is the fifth field) I believe you can simply use:

```
=GETQUOTE("PETR4.SA")
```

I'm not certain this works to return the current price when markets are open, but it does return the last trade price when markets are closed.

Comment: You're correct, but please note I'm actually trying to get the quote from `TODAY()-1`, i.e., the previous day.